trigger logic app from Azure Service bus in sequance
I am looking forward to your advice on the following -
I have a requirement where the logic app would trigger from Azure Service bus in sequence (FIFO) and wait for the previous instance of the logic app to get complete (either successful or failed).

I have done the configuration on -

Az Service Bus topic: Enforce Message Ordering
Logic App: Concurrency Control On and Degree of Parallelism to 1.
However, I have noticed it doesn't give the desired results, every time.
The issue is: the Logic app is not triggering in the proper sequence - FIFO.
Can I get some suggestions on this please..
Thanks,

What are you trying to do and what is the issue you are facing? and also provide your deisgn.

The issue is: that the Logic app is not triggering in the proper sequence - FIFO.

You can use When a message is received in a topic subscription (peek-lock) as the trigger. This trigger contains an option called Session Id --> Next Available which will get the Messages in FIFO using Session Id. This option is not available in Auto Complete, It is only present in peek-lock.

Then in Service Bus Enable below 2 options(Support Ordering while creating topic and Enabling sessions while creating subscription):
While Creating Topic:

then while creating subscription inside topic:

And also use Concurrency and Parallelism to 1.
Output:
Sent 2 messages with session id's:

Then it triggers in Order:
1st Message:

2nd Message:


Thanks for your answer, made the changes in SB as you recommended, however, I'm using LA standard and unfortunately, I don't see the SB trigger connector "When a message is received in a topic subscription (peek-lock)" as you used in the screenshots.

Can you please suggest which SB connector I should use with LA Stand?

You have a trigger https://i.imgur.com/90kAAdS.png and inside that you sessions also https://i.imgur.com/1nA84Mx.png, I have used Stateful.

@NaveenSharma, of course I will, but let the problem resolve.

Hey @RithwikBojja, I have configured it accordingly https://imgur.com/a/uRZe2xe but no LA doesn't pick the messages, kindly refer to the attached screenshots. Looking forward to your advice. Thanks

You have to send a message with Session id with it : https://i.imgur.com/rc0wCtb.png , when you have session id then only it will trigger. If there is no session id , then it will not trigger

@RithwikBojja Thank you, please see my configuration https://imgur.com/a/5NgH7Hb is there any thing wrong? still messages are not picking up?

You have to use this trigger https://i.imgur.com/0n0rHS4.png and in that https://i.imgur.com/sw7n0jX.png. I was giving for queue before, you should Topic and then Subscription name. Hope this solves your issue..

Hey @RithwikBojja, in both attached screenshots you are talking about 2 different SB connectors (message available and message received), I'm bit confused.

No it is same Service bus trigger use my latest comment screen shot trigger. I have said to you that yesterday given comment was not right trigger, today's latest comment was right... It is very simple please check the new comment trigger which is When a message is received in a topic subscription (peek-lock)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks the reported issue is resolved.. only messages are flowing very slow.

getting error: ..error code 'VNetPrivatePortsNotConfigured' and error message 'Using this service provider action in stateful .. equal to 2. while completing the msg from topic subscription.

Posted an answer in that question ,please check it @DeepakShaw
